# Set theory intersections and unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm in an intro to discrete mathematics course, and this is a question on my first homework. I showed what I have so far, I think the answer to the first part of the question may be right, but I'm pretty sure my second answer is wrong. can anyone help explain the proper way to reach the answer using unions and intersections.

The records of $200$ students show the following courses taken:

$104$ students took Latin
$103$ students took Greek
$35$ students took Sanskrit
$46$ students took Latin and Greek
$24$ students took Greek and Sanskrit
$9$ students took all $3$
$28$ students took none of these languages

How many students took only Greek?
How many students took Latin and Sanskrit, but not Greek?

$|L| = 104$, $|G| = 103$, $|S| = 35$. 
$|L ⋂ G| = 46$, $|G ⋂ S| = 24$, $|L ⋂ G ⋂ S| = 9$

How many students took only greek? = 
$$
|G| - (|G ⋂ L| ⋃ |G ⋂S| ⋃ |L ⋂ G ⋂ S|) = 103 – (46 + 24 + 9) = 103 – 79 = 24.
$$
How many students took Latin and Sanskrit, but not Greek?  = 
$$
(|L| - |L ⋂ G|) ⋃ (|S| - |G ⋂ S|) – (|L ⋂ G ⋂ S|) = (104 – 46) + (35-24) – 9 = 58 + 11 – 9 = 69 – 9 = 60.
$$

EDIT:

I made this vendiagram to show known and missing quantities, assuming my first answer of how many students took only greek was correct. [image: Vendiagram]

2nd Edit:

this is my new answer for the first portion |G| - (|G ⋂ S| ⋃ |G ⋂ L|) + | L ⋂ G ⋂ S | = 103 – (24+46) + 9 = 103 – 70 + 9 = 33+9 = 42

final edit:

Found the answer to the second portion to be zero, see comments for  details.

finished diagram

[image: Finished Diagram]

Comment: Hint: the set of students who took all three languages is a subset of both the set of students who take Greek and Latin and the set of students who take Greek and Sanskrit (in fact it is the intersection of those two sets).

Comment: thanks for tip Dasher.   I tried to put a vendiagram image in my post but I don't think it's showing up. But I was thinking that if I found out how many students took only latin and only sanskrit (like i did for those who took only  greek) It would make it easier to fill in the overlapping portion of the diagram of greek and sanskrit.

Comment: You subtract number of students that take all courses trice which is wrong. This is about your first problem.

Comment: Oh wow, it's cool how the diagram makes that more obvious. so the answer to how many students took only greek would actually just be |G| - (|G⋂L| U |G ⋂ S|) as opposed to what I put in my initial post, so 103 - (46+24) which is 33. I dont know why but i feel like i'm missing something though.

Comment: I would need to add |L⋂G⋂S| to the answer (33) that I got, since it is being subtracted twice (as part of |G⋂L| and as part of |G ⋂ S|, so 42, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $60$ can't be the answer to your second question, since only $35$ students took Sanskrit *at all*.

**Hint**: Don't forget that $$|G\cup L\cup S|=|G|+|L|+|S|-|G\cap L|-|G\cap S|-|L\cap S|+|G\cap L\cap S|.$$ You are given all but one of the values on the right-hand side directly, and you should be able to determine the value on the left-hand side fairly simply. Solve for the remaining value. Do you see how finding this allows you to answer the second question?

**P.S.**: Good fix for your first part.

Comment: Thanks for the hints....i wrestled with it for awhile and I finally figured out that "28 students took none of these languages" does actually have something  to do with finding the answer. so |G∪L∪S| is going to equal all of the students to took any of these languages, so 200 total students minus the 28 who took none of these languages. |G∪L∪S| = 172. then some algebra and I got to |L∩S| = 9.

Comment: Nicely done! So, you've concluded that $|L\cap S|=9.$ How does that let you answer the second question?

Comment: i got to that by this equation 172 = 103+104+35-46-24-x+9, with x being |L∩S|.

Comment: well if 9 students took latin and sankrit, and 9 also took latin, sankrit, and greek. then 0 students took only latin and sankrit, right? atleast thats the visual I get when looking  at the vendiagram i created.

Comment: Bingo! "Bonus points" if you can figure out how many students took only Latin, and how many students took only Sanskrit. That should let you fix and complete the Venn diagram (don't forget the exterior!) and check all your answers, as well as answer any other questions that might be asked about this situation.

Comment: Only Latin = |L| - (|G∩L| + |L∩S|) + |L⋂G⋂S|
= 104- (46+9) +9 = 58    

Only Sankrit = |S| - (|G⋂S| + |L∩S|) + |L⋂G⋂S|
= 35 – (24 + 9) + 9 = 11

Comment: And done! Nice work.

Comment: Thanks! i'm filling in the vendiagram, i put the outter rectangle or "universal set" as the 200 students, how should I represent the 28 students who didn't take any of these languages on the diagram?

Comment: Just put "$28$" inside the rectangle, but outside all the circles.

Comment: Incidentally, three of the regions of your current diagram are incorrectly filled. For example, one of them should say $0,$ as you determined. It's also worth noting that, when all $8$ regions are filled in, there will be no need to list the totals.

Comment: Woops, updated it to reflect proper numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Let Go be the set of students who only took Greek and let LG, SG and LSG be the sets of intersections of L and G, S and G and L, S and G respectively. Then |Go|=|G|-|LG|-|SG|+|LSG|.

Comment: It is not true.

Comment: You are right, I just noticed. How do I delete an answer on mobile?

Comment: You cant delete an answer on the mobile app.

Comment: I edited the answer, it should be correct now.

Comment: The theorum in my text is starting to make a little sense now: |A ⋃ B ⋃ C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A ⋂ B| - |B ⋂ C| - |A ⋂ C| + | A ⋂ B ⋂ C |